# Creating a Bell icon

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to create the bell icon as shown in the below image.

[image]

I can create the lower part but I am unsure on how to create the top part.
My initial idea was to use a rectangle and a semi-circle, but it didn't work well

[image]

How can I go about creating this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one method.

1. Drop a vertical guide, and draw half the bell using the Bézier tool <kbd>B</kbd>. If you don't get the shape exactly right the first time, you can edit the curve handles by clicking and dragging them
2. Duplicate it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, flip horizontal <kbd>H</kbd>, then using the Select and Transform Objects tool <kbd>S</kbd>, move into position using Snapping to Cusp Nodes to make them touch exactly
3. Select all, then select all the nodes using the Select by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, and hit Join Selected Nodes [image] in the controls bar along the top.

[image]

Another fun variation on this (because who doesn't like a bit of fun), is to create a Clone <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> of the initial shape, flip it horizontal, then you can edit the nodes and curves, and the result will be reflected automatically by the Clone.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I simply traced out the bell you made.

Comment: @Art - Yeah, you can do that too!! I often trace over an image with the Bézier tool to replicate a particular shape.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to create shapes and use boolean operation.
One thing to note is that create the shape first ,include the shapes's stroke. if you don't do that，something wrong will happen when you do boolean operation. show you the image i test.[image]

I've made a simple image-teaching for you:

[image]

Comment: hey, thx for the response, this almost seems to be working except, I couldn't get the bottom part to be smoother. Can you show me how  you created this step-by-step?